# Why does SQL Server 2000 behave differently than SQL Server 2008 in the absence of an ORDER BY clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2000

We are using SQL Server 2008 R2. We have a table called PD (6 columns) which has a NO primary key and no index on any column. When we execute the query

```
select * from PD where ESE='bycad'
```

without an ORDER BY clause, we are getting results in different order each time executing the same query. We used to have SQL Server 2000 until two months ago and never faced this problem.

Is this a bug in SQL Server 2008? I know we should use an ORDER BY clause, but why Does SQL Server 2008 deal differently with SQL queries without an ORDER BY clause?

Comment: Use `ORDER BY` if the order matters. That's valid for any rdbms and version.

Comment: You didn't use `ORDER BY` and then are calling lack of ordering a bug?!?!??? Sql 2000 unnecessarily ordering was the bug.

Comment: but why the difference in sql 2000 and 2008.. sql 2000 gives the result set in same order exe cuting multiple times. !!!

Comment: @VigneshNanda: [Why people think some SQL Server 2000 behaviors live on... 12 years later](https://sqlblog.org/2012/02/28/why-people-think-some-sql-server-2000-behaviors-live-on-12-years-later)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any result-set coming from SQL Server is a set. A set does not have an inherent order.

There has never been any order guarantee for rows to come back from a select statement unless "ORDER BY" is specified. (This is true for any rdbms not only SQL Server)

EDIT:
To answer your question, the reason you are seeing a different order with every execution is most likely be "caused" by a parallel scan of the table. Did you get new hardware too? But again, if you need ordered results, you need to specify "ORDER BY".

Comment: Thank you ,but how come sql 2000 give result set in same order for all the time ???  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981502 does this link is a proof for the bug ??? ( because in the bug it is mentioned as different result sets  )

Comment: If you submit a simple query, SQL Server most likely reads the data in  in allocation order. IF the query is also restricted to a single thread, there is a high probability for the data to come back in the same order all the time. This however can be influenced by other queries running at the same time.

When the query is executed in parallel, the different threads read different portions of the table each time causing a different output order each time.

Comment: The bug report you quote talks about different results, not a different order on each execution. There is no guarantee for an order unless explicitly requested. There has never been one and there will never be one. If your query behaved like it was ordered before, that only means that you got lucky. Even in SQL 2000 on a single core with static data you can end up with changing result orders in the right circumstance.

Comment: thanks a lot Sebastian !! stressing on the link was because we were using classical asp to hitthe sql server ( both 2000 and 2008) .the query is formed dynamically when the user tries to access the table.Now i will make the default order by incase if the user doent specify explicitly